# Python 3.5 JSON serialize a Decimal object

Tags: python, json

I need to encode into json a decimal value: `999999.99990000005` while not losing precision and not changing representation to string. Expecting `{ "prc" : 999999.99990000005 }`

From [this post][1] i have this code.

```
import json
import decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

y = { 'prc' : decimal.Decimal('999999.99990000005')}
```

but it produces a string

```
json.dumps(y, cls=DecimalEncoder)

'{"cPrc": "999999.99990000005"}'
```

replacing `str(o)` with `float(o)` in `isinstance` truncates the number.
Any way to get the non-string result?
P.S. I cannot use any external modules like simplejson.

EDIT:
If I keep the value as a string, following produces a string too.

```
>>> x = json.loads("""{ "cPrc" : "999999.99990000005" }""", parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
>>> x
{'cPrc': '999999.99990000005'}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to? You'll almost certainly loose that precision when reading the JSON, as most libraries will bring it in as a float.

Comment: What's wrong with the string result? Why can't you use that?

Comment: See EDIT in the question as to why I can't keep a string.

Comment: @Steve You say you can't use external modules like simplejson so I assume you're aware simplejson will encode/decode decimal values fro free, right?

Comment: it serializes to a string because your required level of precision is greater than any than can be handled by the basic data types supported by JSON. What you probably want to do is serialize to a string like it's currently doing and then adjust the _deserialization_ process to handle it as a Decimal

Comment: There's a moose on the loose 

Answer (score 4):

It is not the most pretty but if you insist on using json we can create a custom decoder and have our encoder specify the type when handling decimal data.

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return {
                "_type": "decimal",
                "value": str(obj)
            }
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

The code above adds the decimal type as a flag for our decoder as well as encoding the decimal as a string to keep precision.

```
class DecimalDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json.JSONDecoder.__init__(self, object_hook=self.object_hook, *args, **kwargs)

    def object_hook(self, obj):
        if '_type' not in obj:
            return obj
        type = obj['_type']
        if type == 'decimal':
            return decimal.Decimal(obj['value'])
        return obj
```

The decoder checks for our decimal type flag and if so uses the decimal constructor. For all other instances it uses default decoding

```
input = { 'prc' : decimal.Decimal('999999.99990000005')}
encoded = json.dumps(input, cls=DecimalEncoder)
decoded = json.loads(encoded, cls=DecimalDecoder)
```

The final result should take our input, encode it, and decode the result as a decimal object.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question.
I output Decimal objects surrounded by special character `. Then remove it and the double-quote from text.

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return '`'+str(o)+'`' #` is special, will be removed later
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

json.dumps(y, cls=DecimalEncoder).replace("\"`",'').replace("`\"",'')
```